# Hibernate one to one relationship from a table to multiple tables using xml

Tags: oracle, hibernate, one-to-one, multiple-tables

Am using hibernate with one-to-one mapping from one table to multiple different tables.

I have 3 tables `Customer`, `NormalCustomer`, `PreviligedCustomer` .

`CstId` is the primary key in `Customer` table and it is the primary and foreign key in `NormalCustomer`, `PreviligedCustomer` table. I have a sql which does left outer join on these three table to fetch different column values from three tables.

Problem: For first time, `NormalCustomer`/`PreviligedCustomer` table is empty. These 2 tables will be updated by some other process. After doing some udpates on `Customer` obj and saving it creating a new row `NormalCustomer` and `PreviligedCustomer` with the same `CstId` of `Customer`.

note: For a particular `CstId` in `Customer` table there exists one or multiple rows

Required Solution: I don't want a row to be persisted in `NormalCustomer`/`PreviligedCustomer` tables unless there exists a row in `NormalCustomer`/`PreviligedCustomer` for the `CstId` from `Customer`.

Mappings: 
***Customer.hbm.xml***

`<one-to-one name="NormalCustomer" class="com.test.NormalCustomer" cascade="save-update, merge"/>
<one-to-one name="PreviligedCustomer" class="com.test.PreviligedCustomer" lazy="false" fetch="join" cascade="save-update, merge"/>`

***NormalCustomer.hbm.xml***
`<one-to-one name="Customer" class="com.test.Customer" constrained="true" />`

***PreviligedCustomer.hbm.xml***
`<one-to-one name="Customer" class="com.test.Customer" constrained="true" />`

Answer (score 0):

Think there are couple of ways to handle this:

1. You could conditionally save them (manually) instead of using 'cascade=SAVE-UPDATE'.

   - In this case, you would first save the Customer Entity and requery.
   - The query would retrieve existing NormalCustomer/PrevilegedCustomer records if any (e.g. Customer.getNormalCustomer will show records if other process inserted it).
   - Update the child objects as necessary
2. You could carry on with SAVE-UPDATE but after initial save of Customer entity check for your desired condition. If it is not met then delete the new records from NormalCustomer/PrevilegedCustomer.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.. if there are less number of records this will not have any problem. But, this will increase the number of database hits and this is proportional to the number of records. any suggestions plz

Comment: you can also add a flag in customer table to indicate if Normal Customer or Privileged Customer are populated.. use this flag to conditionally save dependant customer objects

Comment: I had a column in customer table to signify whether its a Noramal or Privileged customer but there is no column in Normal/Privileged tables to signify which table is Normal/Privileged other than id column